# Java: pass error by boolean, null pointer or exception?

Tags: java

I think this is an easy but important question.

I am writing a class with a function:

```
public MyClass myFunction(MyClass mc) { ... }
```

In this function, it changes some state of mc and return it back. I understand it is not necessary as mc is change in place. The reason why I want to return MyClass is to use null to indicate an failed update.

I could potentially change the return type to boolean and use false to indicate an error:

```
public boolean myFunction(MyClass mc) { ... }
```

But I remember I have read an article quite long time ago saying this is not a good practice (although I forgot the detail and why).

I could certainly use exception to represent an error:

```
public void myFunction(MyClass mc) throws MyException { ... }
```

But I get a feeling this is too heavy weighted.

My personally opinion is that if the error is meaningful system wide, then exception should be used. If the error is only meaningful for the caller and the function, then exception should not be used. But shall I use null or false to indicate the error in this case?

What is the best practice do you think? Please let me know your opinion.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Is the failure an expected part of the update process?  Or is it something that only happens when it all goes disastrously wrong?

If it is a truly exceptional condition, then you should prefer to use an exception.  Return values for this sort of thing tends to get ignored (just look at some of the terrible boolean returning `File` functions, like `mkdirs`)

If failure is an expected part of trying to do an update, then you should return either a boolean or some sort of status object.

Comment: The biggest pain of `File`'s design is when you string several such calls together and whichever fails, there is no sense to go on. The author should really care about that question: will it make me write godawful code where I need to wrap every single action in an `if (!action) throw SomeException`?

Answer (score 0):

The practice that's generally frowned upon is using some sort of return code (an int or such) in lieu of throwing an exception. If a failed update is a "normal" behavior, returning a boolean is fine. Collection.add does this, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

From three options you listed, I would *not* use first one.

```
public MyClass myFunction(MyClass mc) { ... }
```

In this case, myFunctions either returns it's parameter (mc) or returns null - only two options are available, so it's basically same as

```
public boolean myFunction(MyClass mc) { ... }
```

As Steven Schlansker said, you should decide whether failed update is really exceptional state or something expected which should be handled by user.

One additional thing to note: if you decide to implement it as method returning boolean (not throwing exception) then I would suggest you may sure that *no change or all changes* are done to *MyClass mc* object.

For example if myFunction is supposed to update 3 fields (*x,y,z*) in MyClass. If you call *myFunction(mc)* and it's able to update two of them  (*x,y*) and fails when updating third (*z*), then it returns *false*. Your *MyClass mc* object is then in inconsistent state, because *x and z* were updated, but *z* was not. This may cause further problems if user decides to keep using existing *mc* object. If you decide to implement *myMethod* as method trowing exception, it may easier to understand that object may be in invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the caller function.

If caller  function  need the value of that object

```
             then you should return Null in case of failure 
             and return the OBJECT in case  of success
```

If caller function need only the status of object whether it is updated or not

```
             then return true in case of success 
             and return false in case of failure
```